# How to reference VS 2012 portable class library from unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I created a portable C# class library in VS 2012 from sources of on older project, but if I try to add a reference to the new library in a unit test library targeting .NET 4.0, it says:

Unable to add a reference to project '(portable project name)'. The current project's target framework is not one of or compatible with the target frameworks of Portable Library project '(portable project name)'.

How do I test the portable library?

Thanks.

-John

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using? MSTest? NUnit?

Comment: NUnit does not complaint about this.

Comment: Oh, found it.  I was using the Microsoft stuff.  It appears I needed to bump the test from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5, as the portable library was targeting .NET 4.03, because it needed the XML stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens when the portable library selected profile does not match the target platform chosen for a project that references it. What are the platforms that you are targeting from your PCL? Note that if you target .NET 4.0.3 and not .NET 4 then it can be referenced from a project that targets .NET 4.0.